# Combinatorial proof. What is this question asking?

Tags: combinatorics

Show for sums over all $i_1 + i_2 + \ldots + i_k = n, i_j \geq 0$, that 
$$
\sum P(n;i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_k) = k^n
$$

What is the index? I'm not even sure how to expand the LHS.

**Update:** $P$ is permutation. If the downvote was because there was something unclear, please let me know.

Comment: Presumably it's the sum over all $k$-tuples of nonnegative integers $(i_1,\ldots,i_k)$ with $i_1 + \ldots + i_k = n$.  But what is $P$?

Comment: I think it's the multinomial coefficient $\binom{n}{i_1,\ldots,i_k}$.

Comment: @DouglasS.Stones Yeah, I knew that, but I didn't know what was being indexed. At least it wasn't apparent to me.

Comment: @AlanH: I believe that Brian M. Scott's answer does contribute to the community, so at the moment I am not going to delete this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to expand it to make it readable, but the summation can be written like this:

$$\large\sum_{i_1+\ldots+i_k=n\atop{i_1,\dots,i_k\ge 0}}P(n;i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k)\;.$$

Alternatively, it’s

$$\sum\left\{P(n:i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k):\sum_{j=1}^ki_j=n\text{ and }i_1,\dots,i_k\ge 0\right\}\;.$$

I can’t be sure of helping with the proof, though, until you tell us what $P(n;i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k)$ is. I’m going to guess that it’s the number of distinguishable permutations of a set of $n$ objects of $k$ types, $i_j$ being the number of indistinguishable objects of type $j$ for $j=1,\dots,k$. That makes your theorem a special case of the [multinomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).

Count the functions from $\{1,\dots,n\}$ to $\{1,\dots,k\}$ in two ways. You can think of such a function as an assigment of labels $1,\dots,k$ to the integers $1,\dots,n$. The term $P(n;i_1,\dots,i_k)$ is the number of ways to assign $i_1$ labels $1$, $i_2$ labels $2$, ..., and $i_k$ labels $k$.